# Programmatic NavigationLink selection change between detail views causes issues

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

In my app, I have a main list view with `NavigationLink`s to detail views. There is an `onURLOpen` modifier on the main view that will change a state selection variable to navigate to the appropriate detail view (using tagged NavigationLinks that are bound to the selection variable).

This works perfectly well as long as the app is on the main list view (the correct detail view will be pushed). However, if the app is already on a different detail view, the app will pop the old detail view, push the correct detail view, but then pop the correct view and end up back on the main view.

GIF of the issue:

[image: GIF of the issue]

This simplified code illustrates the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    @State private var selection: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(selection: $selection),
                    tag: 1,
                    selection: $selection) {
                    Text("Option 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(selection: $selection),
                    tag: 2,
                    selection: $selection) {
                    Text("Option 2")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Options")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var selection: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch selection {
            case 1:
                Button {
                    selection = 2
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to Option 2")
                }
            case 2:
                Button {
                    selection = 1
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to Option 1")
                }
            default:
                Text("No option selected")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Option \(selection ?? 0)")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior for `NavigationLink`? Is there a better way of doing this? I'd be grateful for any pointers.

So far, I've tried adding extra invisible `NavigationLink`s, `NavigationLink` with `isActive: Binding<Bool>`, the `isDetailLink` modifier, and an `ObservableObject` instead of a `Binding`.

Tested in Xcode 12.5 / iOS 14.5.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a binding, I would use an `ObservableObject`. There seems to be an issue with NavigationLink that will cause the views to bounce like that. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64776820/7129318), but I couldn't remember why the `ObservableObject` worked. I still haven't found what I based my answer on, but it does seem to correct the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, that doesn't work in this case, I'm still seeing the same behavior, even with an `ObservableObject`.

Comment: I am hoping it is resolved in the next iteration. Not holding my breath. It is more alchemy than coding to fix. Good luck.

Comment: It looks like this may have been a new implementation of an old bug introduced in 14.5 see [https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677333](SwiftUI NavigationLink pops out by itself) and [https://forums.swift.org/t/14-5-beta3-navigationlink-unexpected-pop/45279](https://forums.swift.org/t/14-5-beta3-navigationlink-unexpected-pop/45279). There are a couple of workarounds being discussed as well as the reminder to me that adding a `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` can often help.